# Creating a Java Class using source code in a string

Tags: java, string, class

I have a String which contains the source code of an entire java class.
My intention is to create a new class in another project folder using the code in this String.
All this is to be done by code, not manually.

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: You need to checkout ClassLoaders

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `String`, I'm assuming you are talking about a class in Java source code form. If you are targeting JRE 1.6 or higher, you can use the `JavaCompiler` interface for turning this source code into a compiled Java class.

See [Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some usefull link

- [How to programmatically generate .class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195507/how-to-programmatically-generate-class-files)
- [Best Library for programatically inspecting Java class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164378/best-library-for-programatically-inspecting-java-class-files)
- [how to create java file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762080/how-to-create-java-file-programmatically)